# How to access the uid of a google-registered user for our Firestore collection?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am creating a flutter app. The point is that in my database, I want the users to be recognized with their uid. For users registered with email & password, there is no problem because I can easily access to their uid with `user.uid`. But when the user registers with his google account, I don't know how to access to his uid. I just know how to access to his id which is different by running `_user.id`. How to access the user's uid in this case? Here's the code:

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  GoogleSignInAccount? _user;

  // create user object based on firebase user

  Users? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
    return user != null ? Users(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // auth change user stream
  Stream<Users?> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }
//register with email & psswrd
  Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);

      User? user = result.user;
      await DatabaseService(uid: user!.uid).updateUserData('new user', 0);

      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
Future signInithGoogle() async {
    try {
      final result = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (result == null)
        return await DatabaseService(uid: _user!.id)
            .updateUserData('new user', 0);
      _user = result;

      final googleAuth = await result.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );

      await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    } catch (e) {}
  }
```

The 'updateUserData' function creates a new record for the user when he registers. The DatabaseService class contains all the functions related to Firestore. here it is:

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({required this.uid});
  // collection reference
  final CollectionReference userCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  Future updateUserData(String name, int points) async {
    return await userCollection.doc(uid).set({
      'name': name,
      'points': points,
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)`, you get back a `UserCredential`, which is the same that you get back from `await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(...)`.

So you can get the UID from the `UserCredential` in both cases with:

```
var credentials = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
var uid = credentials.user!.uid
```

---

If you're [listening to auth state changes](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state), then that will fire when you sign in with any provider, and you'll get a `User?` object. So you can get the UID from that with:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User ${user.uid} is signed in!');
    }
  });
```